# Autotools/Automake : the good way to add include path

Tags: path, include, autotools, automake

I have a C++ project using autotools for compiling under a Linux environment.
All includes path i wrote in were relative (ex : -I../path0/inc -I../path1/path2/inc -I../../../path3/inc).

Everything was fine until i decide to build my project in tree-build directory because all object files were among the source ones.

Of course, compilation does not work anymore as i expected.

So, there are my questions :

1. Do i have to add myself @srcdir@ in front of each include ? (ex: AM_CPPFLAGS = -I**@srcdir@**/path0/inc -I**@srcdir@**/../path1/inc)
2. Or what is the good way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do i have to add myself @srcdir@ in front of each include ? (ex: AM_CPPFLAGS = -I@srcdir@/path0/inc -I@srcdir@/../path1/inc)
> 2. Or what is the good way to do this ?

To properly support out-of-tree building, yes, you need to explicitly express include directories relative to the source directory.  Also any other source-tree paths in command-line arguments, except only those expressed via `make` automatic variables representing prerequisites of the rule.

Personally, however, I prefer to use the `$srcdir` and / or `$top_srcdir` variable provided by Automake instead of the `@srcdir@` substitution from Autoconf.

Comment: I prefer `$srcdir` mainly because its level of abstraction is better matched to `Makefile.am`.  I generalize this to all Autoconf output variables: one should use the variable form in `Makefile.am` files.  The `@`-delimited form is appropriate for use in actual templates such as `Makefile.in`, but where you use Automake together with Autoconf you will not work directly with makefile templates.